# Selenium, Firefox and GeckoDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, geckodriver

I have a question and a problem.

**Question**:
By using Selenium 3.4.0 what is the latest version of Firefox that doesn't require GeckoDriver to run tests. Because using Firefox 45 i can run tests without GeckoDriver, although i thought it is required.

**Problem**:
I'm trying to use Firefox latest version 53.0, Selenium 3.4.0 and GeckoDriver 0.16.0
I set Firefox to the PATH. I set the path properties for Gecko as follows in this class: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzW7p.png)
 , Stack trace:

```
1493481035911   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:32281 1493481036538  geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser \\?\C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"] 1493481037661 addons.manager  ERROR   startup failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm :: FileUtils_getDir :: line 70"  data: no] Stack trace: FileUtils_getDir()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:70 < FileUtils_getFile()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:42 < validateBlocklist()@resource://greJav/amSocdruilpets /eArdrdoorn:M arnageers.ojusrmc:e6:7/1/ g<r es/tmaordtuulpe(s)/@ArdedsoonuMracnea:g/e/rg.rjes/mm,o dluilnees /1A6d5d7o:n MNaSn_aEgReRrO.Rj_sNmO:T_INIT8I3A4L I<Z EsDt:a rAtdudpo(n)M@arneasgoeurr cies: /n/ogtr ei/nmiotdiualleized
s/AddonManager.jsm:3129 < observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:65
[GFX1]: Potential driver version mismatch ignored due to missing DLLs 0.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0
1493481041925   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 54083
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2570: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, moz:firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@150c158, version=, platform=ANY, firefox_profile=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile@4524411f}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '8c03df6', time: '2017-03-02 09:30:17 -0800'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-HUOROU4', ip: '192.168.43.167', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:293)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:272)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:267)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:130)
    at Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

Comment: dont use images for code... just paste the code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to address your question one by one:

1. `By using Selenium 3.4.0 what is the latest version of Firefox that doesn't require GeckoDriver to run tests` - With Selenium 3.4.0 you can use Mozilla Firefox 47.x without gecko driver. From Mozilla Firefox 47.x on-wards gecko driver is mandatory.
2. With Selenium 3.4.0, geckodriver v0.16.1 & Mozilla Firefox 53.0 this piece of code works fine:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
   DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
   WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
   driver.get("http://google.com/");
   ```

Moreover, if you are using any extensions in your default Firefox profile either you need to disable/delete them or create a new Firefox profile for your automation work.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Same error. I even changed location of the driver to same as yours. I edit my post with a bigger stack trace.

Comment: @R.Ro Are you using any extensions in your default Firefox profile? If so either you need to disable them or create a new Firefox profile for your automation work.

Comment: The issue seems to be within BeforeMethod annotation. Where is that in your code?

Comment: in BeforeMethod i simply call the class where the driver is created. The class consists of System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://google.com/");              And i don't run any extensions. I just downloaded Firefox

Comment: @R.Ro You simply can't provide `google.com/`, you have to provide the reference of the markup language as well as `http://google.com/` Try with the updated code & let me know the status.Thanks

Comment: this is my class `package credentials;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class LogInClass {

 public WebDriver driver;

 public void loginMethod() {

  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");

  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  // driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.get("http://google.com/");

 }

 public WebDriver getDriver() {
  return driver;
 }

}
`

Comment: Can you update your Question with all these information and the exact error for proper analysis? Remember to pass the URL with the markup language e.g. `http://google.com/`

Comment: i changed my post. Attached a picture of my class.

Comment: @R.Ro Why are you using this `public WebDriver getDriver() { return driver; } }` ? As per your code it is not needed. Put the loginMethod() under `@Test` Annotation for TestNG to execute.

Comment: I do so. I just changed that at the moment for simplicity.

Comment: @R.Ro You shouldn't do that. Else TestNG will fail to find your testcase to execute. Is it all working fine now?

Comment: I edite and attached a new picture and new stack trace. Thank you for the support!

Comment: I don't see any error in your code now. Can you kill all the previously started instances of gecko driver from your Task Manager or restart your system and test it again. Update me the status. Else I will TeamView (version 12) your desktop.

Comment: I did try it. Killed them all but still. Give me a moment i will try it once more and reboot my pc. Thank you.

Comment: @R.Ro As a last resort you can run the CCleaner to wipe out all the rotten stuff from your PC. Install TeamViewer version 12 on your PC so I can remotely work on it.

Comment: Wow i did reboot my pc and it actually works now. I'v been killing the processes and rebooting eclipse but no the pc. No ideas how it is connected but it actually works now. I'm really thankful for this awesome support!

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help you. Thanks

Comment: I have to downvote this answer due to incorrect information. All versions 3.x of Selenium support running against Firefox 47 without using geckodriver. Doing so in 3.x requires setting an additional capability to do so, but it's perfectly possible.

Comment: @JimEvans Thanks for the valuable information. I will surely get back to you with the status with Mozilla 47.x

Comment: @JimEvans I have tried with Selenium 3.4.0 to run against Firefox 47, I face the `java.lang.IllegalStateException` with `The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;` I have used the following capabilities:   DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  dc.setCapability("firefox_binary", "C:\\Mozila Firefox47\\firefox.exe");
  dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
  WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc); Can you help me in setup out wihtout using gecko?

Comment: The `marionette` capability must be set to `false` to use the legacy driver. In fact, setting it to `true` is exactly what tells WebDriver to use geckodriver.

Comment: @JimEvans Thanks a ton, with the marionette capability set to false, my code is opening the Mozila Firefox 47.0, but it crashes soon after. Do you want me upgrade Firefox to 47.0 to 47.0.1 or 47.0.2 for stability?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "crashes soon after." The term "crash" is so overloaded by most people that it is virtually meaningless. Whether you upgrade to a later minor release of Firefox 47 or use the ESR release of Firefox 45 does not matter to me. My concern in this case is the factual inaccuracy of your answer.

Comment: @JimEvans Thanks. Mozilla Firefox 47.0.1 runs smooth with Selenium 3.4.0 without gecko.